# Writing a `Company` backend: how to give control to the next backend?

Tags: company-mode

I wrote a backend for COMPANY.

```lisp
;;----------------COMPANY BACKEND-----------------------------

(defvar oef-mode-completions '()
  "The content of this variable is generated automatically for COMPANY completion."
  )

(setq oef-mode-completions
      (append  oef-answers-options
           oef-definitions-commands
           oef-commands
           oef-definitions-special-commands
           oef-doc-commands
           oef-storage-types
           oef-menu-exo-init-types
           oef-menu-doc-init-types
           oef-defined-variables
           oef-comparison-operators
           oef-language-reserved-words
           oef-definitions-wims-functions
           oef-wims-functions
           oef-definitions-slib-scripts
           oef-slib-scripts
           oef-pari-functions
           oef-maths-functions
           oef-random-functions
           oef-canvasdraw-commands))

(defun company-oef-mode-backend (command &optional arg &rest ignored)
  (interactive (list 'interactive))

  (case command
        (interactive (company-begin-backend 'company-oef-mode-backend))
        (prefix
         (and (eq major-mode 'oef-mode)
              (company-grab-word))
         )
        (candidates
         (remove-if-not
          (lambda (c) (string-prefix-p arg c))
          oef-mode-completions))
;;      (meta (format "This value is named %s" arg))
        )
  )

(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-oef-mode-backend)
```

It's working but it doesn't give the control to the next backend.
If I look at the documentation `C-h v company-backends` I read :

> ‘prefix’: The backend should return the text to be completed.  It must be
>   text immediately before point.  Returning nil from this command passes
>   control to the next backend.

Until now my code return the word or an empty string that's why the next backend is ignored.

Comment: Note: if you write a `completion-at-point-function(s)`, it will work with Company as well as with the built-in completion facilities.

Answer (score 1):

If found this solution :

In the `prefix` part, the 3 letters before the point are compared with a list of 3 letters (I called this list oef-candidats). If there is a match, the `candidates` part make a popup suggestions. If not, the `prefix` part return nil so the next backend is called automatically.

```
;;----------------COMPANY BACKEND-----------------------------

(defvar oef-completions '()
  "The content of this variable is a list of keyphrases (keywords...).  It's generated automatically for COMPANY completion." 
  )

(defvar oef-grabed-word nil
  "The content of this variable is get before point by company-mode."
  )

(defvar oef-candidats nil
  "List of candidats.  Made of Three first letters of items in oef-completion."
  )

(setq oef-completions
      (append  oef-answers-options
           oef-definitions-commands
           oef-commands
           oef-definitions-special-commands
           oef-doc-commands
           oef-storage-types
           oef-menu-exo-init-types
           oef-menu-doc-init-types
           oef-defined-variables
           oef-comparison-operators
           oef-language-reserved-words
           oef-definitions-wims-functions
           oef-wims-functions
           oef-definitions-slib-scripts
           oef-slib-scripts
           oef-pari-functions
           oef-maths-functions
           oef-random-functions
           oef-canvasdraw-commands))

(defun oef-make-candidats()
  "Make a list of candidats (3 first characters) to detect if oef-mode-backend is required."
  (interactive)
  (let ((mylist oef-completions)(myword))
    (while mylist
      (setq myword (pop mylist))
      (if (> (length myword) 2)
      (add-to-list 'oef-candidats (substring myword 0 3))
    ))))

(defun company-oef-mode-backend (command &optional arg &rest ignored)
  "Detect if company-oef-mode-bakend is required.  If yes company-oef-mode-backend will sugest competions.  If not the next backend is called."
  (interactive (list 'interactive))
  (case command
    (interactive (company-begin-backend 'company-oef-mode-backend))
    (prefix
     (setq oef-grabed-word (company-grab-word))
     (if (and (eq major-mode 'oef-mode)
          (member
           oef-grabed-word
           oef-candidats
           ))
     oef-grabed-word
       nil)
     )      
    (candidates
     (remove-if-not
      (lambda (c) (string-prefix-p arg c))
      oef-completions))
    )
  )

(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-oef-mode-backend)

;;-----------MAJOR MODE----------------------------------------
;;;###autoload
(define-derived-mode oef-mode sgml-mode
  "oef-mode"
  "'Online Exercise Format' mode"

  (oef-make-candidats) ; candidats for completions with company-oef-mode-backend
   )
```